# The Rproj icon is now missing or blank on my Rproj files in Finder on mac

Tags: rstudio

Not sure why but all of a sudden my .Rproj files dont have an icon. See example screenshot.
Running most recent R Studio, tried deleting R studio and reinstalling.  Tried switching the file to have a different default programme then switching back....
[image]

Anyone know how to restore the default icon for this file type?

Comment: I have this issue, too, on a Mac running 12.6.2 (what my org allows).  What OS are you using, @mmarks?

Comment: Running Ventura

Comment: Well, at least we've maybe narrowed it down to it being a Mac thing?

Comment: Seems that they're on it at Posit: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12252

Answer (score -3):

Try right clicking on any R file (which has no icon) > Properties > press "Change" (on the right-hand side of "Open with" under the Type of file) > choose "RStudio"

Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).